# How to prevent Manipulate from using localized names in its frame label?

Tags: manipulate, labeling

In short, the following Mathematica code

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[a Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}], 
  {a, -1, 1}, 
  FrameLabel -> TraditionalForm[y == a Sin[x]]]
```

produces a plot with the (obviously wrong) label

$\textrm{y}=\textrm{a}\$\$\sin(\textrm{x})$.

I am trying to use this in a function which plots and automatically labels other functions, so separating the manipulated variable somehow in the label is not an option.

Comment: Try using `TraditionalForm[y == Dynamic[a] Sin[x]]` instead.

Comment: I am trying to use this in a function which plots and automatically labels other functions, so separating the manipulated variable somehow in the label is not an option.

Comment: What do you want the label to look like? What about `TraditionalForm[y == "a" Sin[x]]`?

Comment: I want the label to look like `TraditionalForm[y == a Sin[x]]` looks when run by itself. I am trying to use this in a function which plots and automatically labels other functions, so separating the manipulated variable somehow in the label is not an option.

Comment: I think it's unclear what would be obviously right....

Comment: `FrameLabel -> (TraditionalForm[y == a Sin[x]] /. a -> ToString[a])`?

Comment: `FrameLabel -> Dynamic[TraditionalForm[y == a Sin[x]]]`?

Comment: `FrameLabel -> (TraditionalForm[y == a Sin[x]] /. a -> ToString[a])` works.

Comment: `FrameLabel -> (TraditionalForm[y == a Sin[x]] /. 
   a -> ToString[a, TraditionalForm])` will be more consistent.

Comment: @Fibonacci [This](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/latex-typesetting-in-mathematica.html) may be relevant. Also search MaTeX on this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If using an other, modified input expression for `TraditionalForm` is not an option and you want the label to look like

```
TraditionalForm[y == a Sin[x]]
```

> [image: png1]

then using a replacement rule, that will replace `a$$` with `a` is an alternative

```
Manipulate[Plot[a Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}], {a, -1, 1}, 
 FrameLabel -> (TraditionalForm[y == a Sin[x]] /. a -> ToString[a, TraditionalForm])]
```

[image: png2]

This approach also works in usage scenarios like

```
Table[
 With[{expr = expr},
  Manipulate[Plot[expr, {x, -Pi, Pi}], {a, -1, 1}, 
   FrameLabel -> (TraditionalForm[expr] /. 
      a -> ToString[a, TraditionalForm])]], {expr, {a Sin[x], a Cos[a x]}}] // Column
```

[image: png3]

or

```
TabView[Table[
  With[{expr = expr}, 
   Manipulate[Plot[expr, {x, -Pi, Pi}], {a, -1, 1}, 
    FrameLabel -> (TraditionalForm[expr] /. 
       a -> ToString[a, TraditionalForm])]], {expr, {a Sin[x], a Cos[a x]}}]]
```

[image: png4]

Answer (score 4):

`Manipulate` automatically wraps 1st argument in `DynamicModule` with the variables defined in its control specifications as the localized dynamic variables. But expressions in its options list are not so treated. So you have to manually make them dynamic.

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[a Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}],
  {a, -1, 1},
  FrameLabel -> Dynamic @ TraditionalForm @ Style[y == a Sin[x], 14]]
```

[image: plot]

Your question isn't clear about how you actually expected the label to look so perhaps what you really want is this;

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[a Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}],
  {a, -1, 1},
  FrameLabel -> TraditionalForm @ Style[y == "a" Sin[x], 14]]
```

[image: plot]

If you require the internal localized variable name to be delocalized programatically, then it can be done by

```
SetAttributes[delocalize, HoldFirst]
delocalize[symbl_Symbol] := 
  First @ StringSplit[SymbolName[Unevaluated @ symbl], "$"]

Manipulate[
  Plot[a Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}],
  {a, -1, 1},
  FrameLabel -> TraditionalForm @ Style[y == delocalize[a] Sin[x], 14]]
```

[image: plot]